# How can I Lock an Azure Table partition in an Azure Function using IQueryable and IAsyncCollector?

Tags: c#, concurrency, locking, azure-table-storage, azure-functions

I'm fiddling with Azure Functions, combining it with CQRS and event sourcing. I'm using Azure Table Storage as an Event Store. The code below is a simplified version to not distract from the problem.

*I'm not interested in any code tips, since this is not a final version of the code.*

```
public static async Task Run(BrokeredMessage commandBrokeredMessage, IQueryable<DomainEvent> eventsQueryable, IAsyncCollector<IDomainEvent> eventsCollector, TraceWriter log)
{
    var command = commandBrokeredMessage.GetBody<FooCommand>();
    var committedEvents = eventsQueryable.Where(e => e.PartitionKey = command.AggregateRootId);
    var expectedVersion = committedEvents .Max(e => e.Version);

    // some domain logic that will result in domain events
    var uncommittedEvents = HandleFooCommand(command, committedEvents);

    // using(Some way to lock partition)
    // {
    var currentVersion = eventsQueryable.Where(e => e.PartitionKey = command.AggregateRootId).Max(e => e.Version);

    if(expectedVersion != currentVersion)
    {
        throw new ConcurrencyException("expected version is not the same as current version");
    }

    var i = currentVersion;
    foreach (var domainEvent in uncommittedEvents.OrderBy(e => e.Timestamp))
    {
        i++;
        domainEvent.Version = i;
        await eventsCollector.AddAsync(domainEvent);
    }
    // }
}

public class DomainEvent : TableEntity
{
    private string eventType;

    public virtual string EventType
    {
        get { return eventType ?? (eventType = GetType().UnderlyingSystemType.Name); }
        set { eventType = value; }
    }

    public long Version { get; set; }
}
```

## My efforts

To be fair, I could not try anything, because I don't know where to start and if this is even possible. Id did some research which did not solve my problem, but could help you solve this problem.

**Do Azure Tables support locking?**
yes, they do: [Managing Concurrency in Microsoft Azure Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/managing-concurrency-in-microsoft-azure-storage-2/). It's called leasing, but I do not know how to implement this in an Azure Function.

**Other sources**

- [Azure Functions triggers and bindings developer reference](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-triggers-bindings/)
- [Azure Functions C# developer reference](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-reference-csharp/)

## Tips, suggestions, alternatives

I'm always open to any suggestions on how to solve problems, but I cannot accept these as an answer to my question. Unless the answer to my question is "no", I can not mark an alternative as an answer. I'm not seeking for the best way to solve my problem, I want it to work the way I engineered it. I know this is stubborn, but this is practice/fiddling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blob leases would indeed work pretty well for what you're trying to accomplish (the Functions runtime actually makes extensive use of that internally).

If, before working on a partition, you acquire a lease on a blob (by convention, a blob named after the partition, or something like that) you'd be able to ensure only a given function is working on that partition.

The article you've linked to does show an example of lease acquisition and release, you can find more information in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee691972.aspx).

One thing you want to ensure is that you flush your collector **before** you leave the lock scope (by calling `FlushAsync` on it)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Could you elaborate? I cannot find a Flush method on ICollector. Are you assuming I'm using Azure Blob storage instead of Azure Table Storage or are you suggesting I should combine the two. As in use table storage for storing my data and blob storage for locking? If so, could you add a code example how this would work in Azure Functions?

Comment: ICollector has a Flush and what you're using above (IAsyncCollector) has a FlushAsync (I updated the answer to match). And yes, you got it. I'm describing a flow where you'd acquire a blob lease to act as the lock before performing operations against the table.

Comment: I had to update Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs to 2.0.0-beta1 to get the `FlushAsync()` method. I've created a gist, can you tell me if this would work? https://gist.github.com/annemartijn0/03bf4020aabe24abeeb97e2edba665c1